Does argo-rollout revert the git changes incase deployment fail
I have a Java application that I deploy using Argo Rollouts via Helm charts, which are stored in an artifact repository. When I need to update to a new version, I simply change the version in the Chart.yaml file and Argo Rollouts automatically deploys the new version.
However, I'm wondering about the rollback process. If I need to revert to a previous version, can Argo CD handle this for me without needing to manually run any commands, either through the CLI or the UI?
In other words, does Argo CD provide automated rollback functionality that allows me to easily revert to a previous version of my application in case of issues or failures during the deployment process?
I'd like to understand if Argo CD can manage the rollback process seamlessly, ensuring that my application remains stable and reliable even in the event of deployment failures or issues with new versions.

Just FYI, you're mixing a few things here: ArgoCD, Argo Rollouts and Kubernetes native rollout features.

my requirement is just to rollback from argocd-cli without manually updating any file

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9570:

Currently auto-sync and rollback do not play nicely together. To perform a rollback auto-sync has to be disabled first and if reenabled happily will sync again to the commit that was rolled back previously.

